# How can I specify user inside the ApiController method if I use ASP.NET Identity Bearer token authentication method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm new to ASP.NET Identity and now trying to use it in my Web Api 2 application. How could I specify user inside my ApiControllers methods?

Comment: What do you mean specify, there is a User property for ApiController

Comment: Here and there I've found something like: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, but ApiController has no HttpContext.